# Viewing iAd profit in itunes connect

Tags: iad

My app has been released about 3 weeks ago and I've a problem in viewing the iAd's profits. I couldn't see the iAd network module in my itunes connect homepage. I've checked out the FAQs and I've did everything as stated in the FAQs which were accepting the iAd contract and having at least an app with iAd. So, may I know what's the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check to see if you'd enabled iAds for the application itself in iTunes Connect?

I've missed this myself a couple of times and have had to resubmit an App to get the change to come into effect as you can only enable / disable iAds when uploading a new version of the App.

Answer (score 0):

Some day's ago I went through same problem. I am unable to locate iAd section in iTunes Connect. I go through many stackoverflow answers but almost all of them is for old iTunes connect. Somehow I find the solution of this problem.

**In new iTunes connect account I don't find any link that show me iAd status and revenue status. For this I go to this link https://iad.apple.com which takes me directly to iAd section where I got everything related to iAd.**

Thank you